# InnoDB log files out of sequence - how can I blast them away?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a MySQL instance running on a VPS that unexpected got shutdown today (physical machine reboot). When it came back up, I had an MySQL error log full of messages like this:

```
140127 17:49:18  InnoDB: Error: page 1846 log sequence number 8869575607
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8869400472
```

I have tried bringing the server back up with `innodb_force_recovery = 6` (`4` doesn't work). This brings the instance back up. However, no amount of table repair is allowing me to run without `innodb_force_recovery = 6`.

My understanding is that InnoDB is transactional and the non-commited writes live in these log files. I don't care about these writes. I just want my supposedly "transactional" database to come back up.

Is it possible to delete all the logs and move my database to a previous good state?

Comment: Setting back the system sequence number would also be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you get that error after a restart, that implies that your supposedly "server" VPS is not a server at all and is in fact a troll who eats your data. Or more seriously this has nothing to do with InnoDB being "supposedly" "transactional" as much as the underlying system it is running on lying about whether it has actually saved your data.

The logs it is complaining about aren't logs for non-transactional data, they are actually the primary transactional mechanism used by InnoDB. Data is accepted, guaranteed to be written to logs on commit, and later flushed to the data pages on disk as necessary. If log writes or flushes are not actually making it to disk as they should, InnoDB may be unable to recover after a crash, as you can see.

Your best bet would be to start up with `innodb_force_recovery` set to any setting that will allow it to run, dump your data with `mysqldump`, and reload it into a completely clean instance. If you're in this bad of a state, merely "fixing" the instance so it will keep running won't be good enough. You need to re-initialize all data structures. And find a new host.